# Finding users with search keywork and return result with order by mutial friends

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am building an application in which I need an advanced user search, like an advanced social network search...

```
Table sl_users 
user_id | full_name | etc
Table sl_user_friends
friend_id | user_id_FK | user_friend_id | accept_status
```

My Query is like

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT user_id , full_name ,
(SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM (

        SELECT CASE WHEN user_id_FK = users.user_id
        THEN user_friend_id
        ELSE user_id_FK
        END AS friendID
        FROM sl_user_friends
        WHERE user_id_FK = users.user_id
        OR user_friend_id = users.user_id
        )a
        JOIN (

        SELECT CASE WHEN user_id_FK =3
        THEN user_friend_id
        ELSE user_id_FK
        END AS friendID
        FROM sl_user_friends
        WHERE user_id_FK =3
        OR user_friend_id =3
        )b ON b.friendID = a.friendID) as mutial_friend

    FROM sl_users

    ) AS users
```

I want results like this but this query is not working.

> user_id | full_name | mutial_friend
>      1         ali           11
>      3         noman         10 
>      4         xyz           9
>
> if i am user 3 and 4 is my friend then i am also friend of 4 . 
>   this query is giving me error like

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'field list'
```

Comment: have you tried using `sl_users` instead of `users` in your inner query? I guess the name given in the last line is not available there, so use the original table name.

Comment: you can use join query to get output.

Comment: yep  i have also tried with orignal name but in the nested query that can get my mutial friend is says that unknown user_id

Comment: any one DB expert  here to help me  ????

Comment: Please help for this issu ??

Answer (score 1):

Use below query with your database. Not tested but i hope it will work for you.

```
select user_id,full_name from sl_users sl left join sl_user_friends slf on slf.user_id_FK=sl.user_id
```

Comment: i am not fetching only user_id and full_name it can check both mutual friend and count them and then order them with this counter

Comment: yes you can modify query based on your requirement. This is just basic query for fetch common data from two tables.